# Excel 2010 VBA: find out if formatting style exists

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I want to check if an formatting style exists in an Excel2010 document.

```
On Error Resume Next

Private Function checkStyleName(ByVal strStyleName As String) As Boolean
    Dim objGivenStyle As Excel.Style

    Set objGivenStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles(strStyleName) ' try to get formatting style out of list
    If objGivenStyle Is Nothing Then
        ' do something
        checkStyleName = False
    Else
        checkStyleName = True
    End If
End Function
```

Problem is, `Set objGivenStlye = ActiveDocument.Styles(strStyleName)` doesn't work at all. What is the best solution - maybe a loop over all existing styles?

THX BKS

Comment: Ok, I'm using `Set objGivenStyle = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles(strStyleName)` right now and everthing works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer didn't work for me.    Here's a function that does work.  It checks if the style name being tested exists and returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
Public Function StyleExists(ByVal styleName As String, ByVal target As Workbook) As Boolean
' Returns TRUE if the named style exists in the target workbook.
    On Error Resume Next
    StyleExists = Len(target.Styles(styleName).Name) > 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Here's an example use of the function:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox StyleExists("Normal", Activeworkbook) ' Should be TRUE.
    MsgBox StyleExists("Unusual", Activeworkbook) ' Should be FALSE unless custom style 'Unusual' is in the active workbook.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
'case sensitive

Private Function checkStyleName(ByVal strStyleName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sCheck As String
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    checkStyleName = False
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook

    sCheck = "x" & strStyleName ' makes the two strings different
    On Error Resume Next
        sCheck = wkb.Styles(strStyleName).Name
    On Error GoTo 0

    If sCheck = strStyleName Then checkStyleName = True
End Function
```